# How do get a "nice" scale-widget in SWT under Gnome?

Tags: java, swt, widget, gnome, scale

I would need a scale-widget in SWT that looks like the following example:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/Scales.htm

If I run this example under Ubuntu (Gnome) the scale looks like this:
http:// book.javanb.com/swt-the-standard-widget-toolkit/ch10lev1sec2.html

But actually I would prefer to have these steps beside the bar.

What can I do?

Thank you,
Tobias

Answer (score 0):

You can change the orientation by setting the style to SWT.HORIZONTAL or SWT.VERTICAL in the constructor, othervise the look depends on the OS or the windowing system you're using.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

I am thinking of using the Swing Slider component (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html) via the SWT-AWT-Bridge (http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Swing-SWT-Integration/index.html).

Comment: Small update: I tried it using the SWT/AWT bridge and under Gnome it works fine. But when I run the app on a Mac, you are not able to move the slider knob.

So I will have to choose an other widget..